# cannot get resources folder into jar when using spring boot maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Im trying to build an executable jar that runs with spring boot, but I cant get the spring xml from the resources folder into the jar. It looks like my outputDirectory is wrong. What is the correct way  to define it such that it is packaged within the jar?

Here is my pom file

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/my-resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>netexchange.exchange.main.ExchangeMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>Matcher-with-config</finalName>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
</build>
```

Comment: Why is there a Spring XML file at all? Have you tried just not including any of this configuration at all and letting the default magic work?

Comment: My goal is to ultimately create many jars from the same source with different spring XML files, so I need this to work

Comment: And you want "different Spring XML files" why? It seems like you haven't read up on the Boot configuration system (which is fairly comprehensive and almost certainly covers your use case with a more flexible arrangement, particularly externalized configuration).

Comment: Because each jar needs different beans. Ill read up more on externalized configuration

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a solution which was to copy the specific resource into question into the folder "src/main/resources". Spring boot build automatically includes all files in that folder, and then you can import them with the annotation "@ImportResource({ "classpath:config.xml" })"

My updated pom looks like this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bitcoin-ethereum</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/matcher</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/common</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>netexchange.exchange.main.ExchangeMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>Matcher</finalName>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
</build>
```